# R log of 0 equals -inf

Tags: r, math

I have a table that contains some 0 values

`example`

```
V1 <- c(100,120,101)
V2 <- c(10004,10010,1010)
V3 <- c(102,120,0)
DF <- log(data.frame(V1,V2,V3))
DF
```

I am trying to visualize this data using a heatmap

```
heatmap(DF)
```

To better appreciate low level variation in the data i need to log transform `DF`.  However, the 0 in the dataset is converted to `-inf`.

```
log(DF)
```

This prevents me from successfully generating the heatmap.

```
heatmap(log(DF))
```

What is the best way to deal with this behavior of log() when working with an enormous DF.

Comment: Many people use log(x+1) if log(x) gives them problems because of log(0).  Or you can replace 0 with a very small positive number.

Comment: You can add a small value, for example `log(DF + 0.001)`. (The built-in function `log1p` gives `log(x + 1)`). Or you can use a different transformation that is defined for zero, like `sqrt()`. Or you can omit the 0s, perhaps making them `NA`. What do you want to do?

Comment: As well as the above suggestion, you could do a different transformation that works on 0s, such as sqrt(x)

Edit: Gregor beat me to the punch by 18 seconds.